# simple Jquery draggable isn't working for me?

Tags: jquery, draggable

Could someone help me out? it's probably something simple i'm overlooking:

```
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>


<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
</script>



<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"
style="position:absolute;width:150px;height:210px;left:2%;top:40%;background-color:#eeeeee;border-radius:12px;border:solid 1px black;font-size:17px;text-align:center">
</div>
```

---

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is broken; your code works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XxaET/) if I load the entire jQuery UI library.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I never seize to amaze myself with these careless errors! I need sleep lol...

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't add to your page **jquery.js**

add this line at the top of the other script tags,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

it works in [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CdaYm/) (external jquery)